# Como gerar imagens drawable para Android a partir do Photoshop

Tags: android, photoshop

Como faço para gerar imagens *drawable* para um aplicativo Android a partir de um arquivo `.psd`?

Tenho o `.psd` com os botões e imagens de *background*, mas não sei como converter isso e utilizar no app que estou desenvolvendo.

Answer (score 3):

Use o plugin [CutAndSliceMe](http://www.cutandslice.me/) para o Photoshop.

Fácil, rápido e prático. Ele gera para todas as densidades.

Answer (score 1):

A partir da versão CC vocÊ pode exportar cada layer do seu projeto separadamente, seja em .jpeg, .png, .gif e etc... Entretanto, se vocÊ ainda não tem esse recurso, vá em file, e selecione a opção (save to web), salvar para web em pt, e selecione os formatos que deseja. Abraços